# Java, converting Fahrenheit to Celsius

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The program is suppose to convert the input temp. from Fahrenheit to Celsius. So if the input is 212F, then it should display:

```
212 deg. F = 100 deg. C
```

Except when I run the program the output is always "0 deg. Celsius". Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I guessing if anything it has to do with the:

```
double fahrenheit = keyboard.nextDouble();
```

But even then I'm not quite sure why. Thanks for your help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;       //keyboard input
import java.text.DecimalFormat; //formatting

public class FahrenheitToCelsius {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //User Input
        System.out.println("Please enter temperature (Fahrenheit): ");
        double fahrenheit = keyboard.nextDouble();

        //Calculations
        double celsius = (5 / 9) * (fahrenheit - 32);

        //Formatting
        DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");

        //Output
        System.out.println("\n" + myFormatter.format(fahrenheit) 
        + " deg. F = " + myFormatter.format(celsius) + " deg. C");

    }

}
```

Comment: `(5 / 9)` make this `(5.0 / 9)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem that results in integer division

try

```
double celsius = (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahrenheit - 32.0);
```